# How would you translate 发刀子 to English?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I was talking to my American friends about mihoyo's storytelling, and this is the phrase that I can think of. But I don't know the equivalent to English for this phrase. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[发刀子](https://jikipedia.com/definition/990814223)

> 一般指小说、漫画、番剧等影视作品中一些特别虐心、令人感动、泪目的剧情。（就好像有人往你身上扔刀子一样）

> It generally refers to some particularly sadistic, moving, and tearful plots in novels, comics, dramas, and films. (As if someone threw a knife at you)

So '发刀子' is basically '[tearjerker](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tearjerker)'

- tearjerker (n): a sentimental story, movie, or song, calculated to evoke sadness or sympathy."
- tear-jerking: (adj/slang) sadness evoking

If we use 发刀子(throw knife) as a verb, it could be translated as "stab readers/viewers in the heart"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still feels like the term 'tearjerker' doesn't really get the comedic part of the phrase, but thank you.

Comment: tearjerker is funny if you imagine a giant holding you in one hand and jerking your body with the other hand like milking a cow until tears come out like milk (there's one other example I could give...)